# UnboundLocalError: pygame music play and stop not working (on keydown)

Tags: python

I'm trying to play and stop a music in my main page.

It's kind of weird.
From my code,
if the user press "m", suppose, the music should be off.
However, the music didn't off. It continue

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'music_playing' referenced before assignment
```

Can someone help me with my code?

```
pickUpSound = pygame.mixer.music.load('test.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
music_playing = True

def mainMenu():
    main = pygame.image.load('menu.jpg')
    screen.blit(main,(0,0))
    while True:
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('m'):
                    if music_playing:
                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    else:
                        pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
                    music_playing = not music_playing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written, `event.type` should be simultaneously equal to `KEYDOWN` and `pygame.K_KP_ENTER`at the same time. The second should be `event.key` instead of `event.type`.

```
if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER:
```

**EDIT**
There seems to be something wrong with the "keypad enter" key, I commented the problematic line (maybe try with another key, for example, I used K_a, and was able to start/stop by pressing "a")

```
import pygame

def mainMenu():
    pygame.display.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode([128,128])
    screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
    #                          
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pickUpSound = pygame.mixer.music.load('test.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    music_playing = True
    #                          
    main = pygame.image.load('menu.jpg')
    screen.blit(main,(0,0))
    while True:
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER:
                if music_playing:
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    print "stopping"
                else:
                    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
                    print "playing"
                music_playing = not music_playing

mainMenu()
```

n.b. When running this code, I see the messages "playing" and "stopping" each time I press any key.

With `if event.key == pygame.K_a:` the music should start/stop by pressing "a".

Comment: Hi, I edited my question, please see the question.. Sorry about it. 
I did the m key previously but have error of unboundlocal

Comment: Since `music_playing` is not defined in the mainMenu function, it is a global variable.  You can read the value of a global variable in a function, but in order to **modify** its value, you have to write `global music_playing` in the function.  The problem does not occur in my code because I moved everything in the function.  See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global_stmt for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: In your code, immediately after the line `def mainMenu():`, insert the line `global music_playing`.